# Why there is no writeStringArray() in Parcel.cpp?

Tags: android, android-framework, parcel

Why there's no writeStringArray() in cpp implementation?
I found there's writeStringArray() in java but not in cpp.
Of course I can simply write one refer to the java code, just wondering why Android didn't provide that interface?
Is there any concern?

Answer (score 0):

```
798 public final void writeStringArray(String[] val) {
799         if (val != null) {
800             int N = val.length;
801             writeInt(N);
802             for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
803                 writeString(val[i]);
804             }
805         } else {
806             writeInt(-1);
807         }
808 }
```

It simply don't need to implement it in C++ since it can be easily implemented in Java too.

Why add more overhead to call a native method and work with it in C++, when you can use Java code?

Comment: Hi Marco,
I have a native service written in C++, and I use binder to communicate with it in my android app (java).
So I have to use the C++ implementation to pass some data to my android app.

Comment: If you have another question create another question to get more answers.